# Get parent parameter on child's new button override

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I have two objects, `Parent` and `Child`. The `Parent` object has a `Url` field.

I am trying to override the child's `Create New` button and I need to be able to tap into the parent's `Url` attribute on the `New` page layout.

Here is the code I have right now, but it's not working:

```
<apex:page standardController="Integration_Type__c" extensions="IntegrationTypeExtension">
    {!debug}
    {!endpoint}  
    <apex:form>   
        <apex:inputField value="{!Integration_Type__c.Name}"/> <p/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class IntegrationTypeExtension {
    private final Integration_Type__c integration_type;
    public String endpoint {get;private set;}
    public String debug {get;private set;}
    public IntegrationTypeExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.integration_type = (Integration_Type__c)stdController.getRecord();
        endpoint = integration_type.Integration__r.Url__c;
        debug = 'test';
    }
}
```

I though that `endpoint = integration_type.Integration__r.Url__c`, would return the current parents attribute.

Comment: What does "Not Working" mean? What is the behavior?

Comment: I try displaying it on the visual force page and it shows empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably would work, except... you have to query for it first. When a page is compiled, all of the field references from the page are turned into a SOQL statement that's called immediately before the constructor is called. This, in turn, is placed in the ApexPages.StandardController parameter that's given to you in the constructor. So, in theory, this should work if you add the following code to your page:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="false" value="{!Integration_Type__c.Integration__r.Url__c}" />
```

However, since it is a "new" record, this still might not work-- you'd have to query for the Integration__c record directly.

To get the parent record, simply query it by ID:

```
if(integration_type.Integration__c != null) {
    endpoint = [SELECT Url__c FROM Integration__c WHERE Id = :integration_type.Integration__c].Url__c;
}
```

Comment: how do i query for it directly? how do I get his ID